# Why static member of class can not be overloaded in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, static, function-declaration

```
#include<iostream>
 class Test {
   static void fun() {}
   void fun() {} // compiler error
};

int main()
{
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

> |4|error: ‘void Test::fun()’ cannot be overloaded|

Comment: So, start with removing the C tag...

Comment: Right a C++ compiler of your own with this functionality. We can call it an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as the standard forbids it directly.

Quoting the `C++14` standard document, chapter § 13.1, "Overloadable declarations"

> 2. Certain function declarations cannot be overloaded
>
>    - Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded.
>    - Member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter types cannot be overloaded if any of them is a `static` member function declaration. [....]